# Best login implementation in PHP/MySQL/Apache

Tags: php, ajax, iframe, authentication

I am building a new website where a user can login.  I see three possible options:

**1. classic type login:**

```
<form action="/login.php" method="POST">

</form>
```

and the submit button goes to `login.php` and validates and redirects if success

**2. ajax type login:**

Same as above but do an ajax call instead and then the javascript redirects.

**3. iframe login:**

Same idea as stackoverflow/openid

What is the most secure and best way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

well, in my opinion options 1 & 2 should use post, and in your code you should make sure the request is post. you should also add in other session logic against spoofing if you want the application to be super secure, but this is preferential to the developer and the application.  i find iframes to be evil and many hackers use iframes to hack unknowing user's accounts.  openid is a trustworthy way to login and is becoming more widely adopted, as well as the facebook version of openid.  i know they use the iframe method, but verification is doubled and i believe https is required to implement these type of logins.

again all of this is just my opinion and mostly reliant on the developer's design and business needs/requirements of the application.

hope this helps :)

Comment: what do you mean by spoofing?

Comment: i'm not sure if you're using a framework or custom code, but most frameworks have this integrated now, but basically this, which was posted prior as another kind of related topic: Preventing session fixation
    Regenerate a new session_id every X number of requests in order to reduce the amount of time an attacker has to steal the id.

    Uniquely identify the client
    Use the IP and/or the User-Agent to uniquely identify the client and check that value on every page load against the ones stored in the session. This is really the only two choices you have to uniquely identify the client.

Comment: here's a good article to read up on spoofing: [link](http://www.nyphp.org/PHundamentals/6_Spoofed-Form-Submissions)